# loading staticfiles in django template causes server error 500

Tags: html, django

I have a base.html file extended by the index.html one. In base I load some static files in the  section, and other in the bottom of the file.

I am trying to use the template tag for loading static files:

```
{% load static %}
```

However, depending where I put it, this works or fails. 
When the tag is on the begining of the base (first line), this always does not work.

It works only when it is on the body section of the base.html and on the begining (just after extend tag) of the index.html.

Where is the correct place to put it ? Should it be called only once ?

EDIT:

DEBUG is set to False. There is no problem when it is set to True.

Comment: Saying you get a 500 error isn’t very helpful. If you use `DEBUG = True` on your dev server so that you get a useful error message. It would be better to actually show what works and what doesn’t, rather than describing the templates.

Comment: There is no problem when it is True. The issue is precisely when it is False.

Comment: Are you running the code locally?

Comment: In that case you should include the error from your logs or admin email.